# How does "for" define a variable in a function?

Tags: python, function, variables, sum

I'm trying to define a function that will find the average length of words in a sentence. Everything is fine, but I just have an inquiry about certain parts of my function, namely, this:

```
random_sentence = str(input('Enter a sentence:'))

def average():
    'Takes the average length of a word in a sentence inputed by user.'
    words = random_sentence.split()
    averageword = sum(len(word) for word in words)/len(words)
    return averageword

print(average())

averageword = sum(len(word) for word in words)/len(words)
```

I understand what sum and len do, however, how does Python know what a 'word' is in "for word in words." Is it predefined somewhere? When I take that phrase out the function work, as it will say word is not defined. I appreciate the clarification.

Answer (score 4):

`for` [is a keyword in Python](http://docs.python.org/dev/reference/lexical_analysis.html#keywords).

When Python executes a program, it transforms the file into a series of *tokens* with [lexical analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_analysis). Afterwards, the tokens get [parsed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing) in order to determine what construct they belong to.

In your case, an [*expression* token](http://docs.python.org/dev/reference/expressions.html#grammar-token-expression) before the `for` makes the construct a [generator expression](http://docs.python.org/dev/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions).

Answer (score 2):

The list `words` is an iterable - it defines an `__iter__` method, which returns an iterator for the list. The `for` keyword calls `__iter__()` on the list, and then calls `next()` on the iterator until a `StopIteration` exception is thrown:

```
In [1]: words = ["a", "b"]

In [2]: i = words.__iter__()

In [3]: i
Out[3]: <listiterator at 0x5cd82b0>

In [4]: i.next()
Out[4]: 'a'

In [5]: i.next()
Out[5]: 'b'

In [6]: i.next()
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
StopIteration                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-e590fe0d22f8> in <module>()
----> 1 i.next()

StopIteration:
```

Some more details about iterables and iterators:

http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#iterator-types
http://getpython3.com/diveintopython3/iterators.html#a-fibonacci-iterator

Answer (score 0):

for x in y requires that that y is a iterable (ie list, dict, string etc.)

and then python iterates through y and each iteration x is defined as y[iteration#]

so basically if y = [1,2,3]

```
for x in y:
    print x
```

will return

1

2

3

Comment: That's the `for` loop, which is not used in the example program.

Comment: Yes, however it is the same thing but written in slightly different form - the for keyword is treated the same by python

Comment: There are significant differences between a for loop and a generator expression. The `for` loop assigns to local variables, whereas generator expressions assign to a temporary (internal) one. Also, observe `from __future__ import print_function;for x in [1,2,3]: print(x);(print(x) for x in [1,2,3])`: unless the generator expression is consumed later, it is not evaluated.

Answer (score 0):

"word" is locally defined in list comprehensions and generator expressions, as well as in for loops. It's like a temporary variable.

Think of it this way by substituting 'x' for 'word':

```
theSum = sum([len(x) for x in words])
```

(I put brackets around it to show that it's like a list). This means "let x be an element in the list 'words'. For every x, calculate its length and make a list out of the results."

you can also think of it like this:

```
list = []
for x in words:
    list.append(len(x))

theSum = sum(list)
```

You can get some gory details of the syntax at [List Comprehensions](http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/list_comprehensions.hawk)

Comment: The question doesn't actually contain any list comprehensions (note the absence of brackets). The `for` occurrences in there belong to generator expressions, which are close relatives of list comprehensions.

Comment: Noted. I put the word "generators" in there to be more accurate.

Comment: Sorry, but it's not a [generator](http://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-generator) either.

Comment: Question: "how does Python know what a 'word' is in "for word in words." Is it predefined somewhere?" Answer: no, it's not predefined but syntactic, it's treated as a temp variable, and it's done this way in for loops, list comprehensions AND generator expressions.

Comment: @Jeremey Again, sorry for nitpicking, but that's inaccurate as well. In Python 2, `x` is only a temporary variable in generator expressions  . List comprehensions and for loops assign to a local variable. In Python 3, list comprehensions use a temporary variable as well.